# Get PDF or TIFF from SSRS reporting service

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services

SQL Server Reporting services capable of exporting report as TIFF.
This is excellent since I want to use report inside my Silverlight application and already have infrastracture for viewing TIFF.

Question is how to GET tiff directly from report server without running report on webpage first?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply but it may be helpful. http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Silverlight-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx - the ready component to integrate SSRS report to the Silverlight application. May be it would be easier to use it instead of TIFF magic? It's our component, I need to confess.

Comment: Yes, is open option but TIFF already in client libs, if I buy your solution I will have to include another component (larger download)

Comment: You're right. It also makes sense to use TIFF extension if you have limited access to the server side and are not able to install a custom rendering extension there.

Comment: Спасибо, а соотечественникам скидка есть? :) I have full access to server-side but still not sure how I will do it. With TIFF download size might be big depending on report size. Also, it will be in SL container and I'm thinking going more "web". Maybe I will do PDF export and just pop up as file download. So it will be easier to code, smaller download and common format..

Comment: Пишите - сделаем :). PDF is a good solution too. However I'm not sure it will be easy to integrate it into SL application. Anyway you will need third party library in order to do this.

Comment: By PDF I mean NOT integrating into SL. To end user it will be regular file download. Run report -> get file from server -> Show SaveAs dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SSRS Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153968.aspx) and call the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) method. This method will give you a specified report as a `Stream`, which can then be shown in your infrastructure to view TIFF's.